# Version error running demo of selenium2library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When I run the rundemo.py from "rtomac-robotframework-selenium2library-893dc2c" demo folder.
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "rundemo.py", line 34, in <module>
import Selenium2Library
File "C:\Development\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\__init__.py",
line 5, in <module>
execfile(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, '..', '..', 'version.py'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Development\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Selenium2Library\\..\\..\\version.py'
```

It looks like I have wxVersion.py not version.py.  I am using windows and python 2.7  64bit.

Comment: This needs much more information. Where do we download "rtomac-robotframework-selenium2library-893dc2c" from? What is supposed to happen when you run the demo?

Comment: I obtained the application from this [website](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library).  I am not sure what is meant to happen but the demo is to test that selenium2library was installed correctly, which i believe has not been.